# Initializing size of struct array after declaration in C?

Tags: c

I've done some searching around, but nothing I've found has answered my question specifically regarding structs:

In my program I have two structures: one contains data, the other contains an array of the first structure (used to make returning struct arrays easier).

I do not know the size of the aforementioned structure array until running a few lines of code. From what I've found there isn't a way to define the size of an array (or any type) after it has already been declared, although I would like to know if this holds true for structs.

If not, is there way to define the size of a previously declared array within a struct without using malloc? Using malloc with struct arrays seems a bit complicated and I haven't been able to wrap my head around it.

```
typedef struct
{
    char **data;
} struct1;

typedef struct
{
    struct1 data[];
} struct2;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Pretend there is code here that finds the size I need
    size = 5;
    struct2 Info;
    Info.data = new struct1[size]; //Clearly this won't work, but does C offer anything comparable?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If length of a sequence of data is determined only at runtime, you should use malloc.

Comment: Using `malloc` is a little more complicated than declaring a static array, but it's what you need. Unless you show your declarations and a little code or example, it's difficult to offer much more help than that.

Comment: This question is not very clear. You can have a *flexible array member* in a struct, and you can have variable-length arrays. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @lurker I have added some example code. This isn't what my actual program looks like, but it keeps it more simple.

Comment: Some info on variable length arrays here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Comment: @EOF I do not know the difference between those two, and I will look them up. I am trying to load all of the files in a directory and all of their data into a structure. I cannot assume the number of files I am dealing with, however, once I've learned the number of files, it will not change for the duration of the program.

Comment: `struct2 *s2p = malloc(offsetof(struct2, data) + sizeof(struct1)*size))`. You now have a `struct2*` pointing to an object you can use as a `struct2` containing `size` `struct1`s.

Comment: @EOF Awesome, perhaps not as complicated as I thought. I have never used offsetof before, and I am receiving the error message "Symbol 'data' could not be resolved." Should the second parameter be instead 'struct2.data'?

Comment: @Lance_P: The syntax in the snippet should be fine. One problem could be that `struct2` must contain more than one named member (and the flexible array member must be the last member), so you would have to change `struct2` to `{char dummy; struct1 data[];}`.

Comment: Gonna go ahead and say that works for now. I'm confident that I'll find a way to break it though. When that happens I may let you know. Thanks.